# How to wait for promise from getting data to return before continuing

Tags: angularjs, promise

```
vm.education = common.dataservice.getAllEducations(currentUser.id); 
vm.education.$promise.then(function(data){                          
     console.log(data);                                               
});

[a bunch of code that also utilizes vm.education]
```

I have the above code in angularJS in my controller.js file. My question is how do I wait for the return of common.dataservice.getAllEducations before continuing on with executing the rest of the code?

If I don't wait for the completion of getting data, then the code that references vm.education will be null.

Comment: Code that needs `vm.education` put in the next `.then()` section

Comment: Must I do that? It's a lot of code, and I would just like to retrieve the information and continue on with the code.

Comment: @Mot1on, `vm.education.then(function(data) { ... } );` , you've got syntax error, drop `$promise`. Wrap codebases that need to be waited into the `then(function() { .. });` Then it should be alright.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with resolve property of [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). This delays the controller until all values have been resolved.

You would use it something along the lines of

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/education', { 
        controller: ['$scope', 'education', function($scope, education) {
          ...
          vm.education = education;
        }, 
        resolve: {
          education: ['common', 'currentUser', function(common, currentUser) {
            return common.dataservice.getAllEducations(currentUser.id)
              .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
              });
        }
      });
  }]);
```